# Examples of Barchart Creation in Struts 2

Tags: java, struts2, jfreechart, struts2-jfreechart-plugin

I need to develop a bar chart using struts2 framework. I have found

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartBarChartDemo1.htm

to develop bar chart using jfreechart. But its not in struts2. I have searched a lot to find example for developing bar chart, but couldn't find a working example.

Would really be grateful if someone could help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

That would be easy to implement if you use [struts2-jfreechart-plugin](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/jfreechart-plugin.html). The plugin helps to separate the logic between the model and view exposing the `chart` result type.

So, you could create the chart in the action and render it executing the result.